No deployments available with an embedding model
I am trying to Import and vectorize data from Azure Blob Storage to Azure AI Search. I have two embedding models deployed in Azure AI Studio - text-embedding-3-small and text-embedding-ada-002. I can see them in the Deployment tab. But when I try to import and vectorize data to AI Search service with using one of these AI Studio Catalog models, I see the "No deployments available with an embedding model" error message. What can be wrong?

I have the exact same situation. It's pretty annoying.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/search/search-get-started-portal-import-vectors?tabs=sample-data-storage%2Cmodel-catalog%2Cconnect-data-storage#supported-embedding-models for the list of allowed embedding models.
Import and vectorize data in Azure only supports text-embedding-3-small if you create that model in Azure Open AI.
If you are creating the embedding model in Azure Foundry (studio) you need to use Cohere-embed-v3-english or Cohere-embed-v3-multilingual
